# MongoDB Java driver : no such cmd: aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am calling the MongoDB aggregate function in my code as :

```
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate( matchUserID, unwindF, matchFUsers,projection);
```

I have tested my code in my localhost, and it works perfect. When I am using the same in another DB (version 2.2.1), it gives this error :

```
com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure: command failed [aggregate]: { "serverUsed" : "<server address>" , "errmsg" : "no such cmd: aggregate" , "bad cmd" : { "aggregate" : .... }
```

Any clue why ?

Answer (score 7):

Based on other answers I've seen to similar questions, it seems most likely that the server is not actually 2.2.1 as you believe.

How are you checking the server's version number?

From the shell, try this:

```
use admin
db.runCommand( {buildInfo: 1} )
```

Comment: I guess it is. I get this when I run your command :
db.runCommand( {buildInfo: 1} )
{
 "version" : "2.2.1",
 "versionArray" : [
  2,
  2,
  1,
  0
 ],
        <other server details.>
}

Comment: That looks right. You're sure it's the same instance your app is connected to?

Comment: i have two version of MongoDB installed in my system, i wrongly started my old version. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

figured out the error. I was using the 2.9 version on the MongoDB Java driver. When I upgraded it to 2.10, it worked perfectly. Thanks folks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error "no such cmd: aggregate", and I tried new version of mongodb 2.4,2.6 from default debian repositories and always receiving this error.

After that installed mongodb-org-server from mongo repo and it worked
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/